# Why can I access this stack-allocated object after its destructor has been called?

Tags: c++, memory-management, scope, stack

> I am working on developing a game and ran across something that I
> cannot understand.  Why can I access this stack-allocated object after
> its destructor has been called?
>
> This class, TextRes, is used to hold the "common name" of a texture
> and a path to the texture resource on disk.  It also holds an
> SDL_Texture* variable, Texture_.

```
class TextRes
{
// class definition truncated
public:
    inline SDL_Texture* text() { return Texture_; }
private:
    char const*     Name_
    char const*     Path_
    SDL_Texture*    Texture_;
};
```

> Another class, TextResMgr, is responsible for the data in this
> Texture_ variable; loading and deleting the texture resource,
> primarily.  MVC design.  TextResMgr has a std::vector<TextRes*>,
> TRvec, where pointers to instances of TextRes are held.
> TextResMgr::push_tr(TextRes&) takes an instance of TextRes by
> reference and adds it to the TextResMgr::TRvec object and loads the
> texture from disk into TextRes::Texture_.

```
class TextResMgr
{
// class definition truncated
    public:
    rt push_tr(TextRes&);    // rt is just a custom enum class used for return type 
    inline SDL_Texture* get_t(size_t _index) {return TRvec[_index].text();}

    private:
    std::vector<TextRes*> TRvec;    
};
```

> The actual instances of TextRes reside in each of the game's "level
> classes" in a struct, and TextResMgr pushes/loads them to
> TextResMgr::TRvec when a level becomes active.

```
// ST_eng_menu.h (a "level"class)

#include "TRL_MainMenu.h"
class ST_eng_menu
{
// class definition truncated
public:
    TRL_MainMenu trl_main;
    char const* text_name = "menu-main";
};

// TRL_MainMenu.h

#include "TextRes.h"
struct TRL_MainMenu
{
    TextRes menu_bg;
    TextRes menu_opt_u;
    TextRes menu_opt_s;

    TRL_MainMenu()
    {
        menu_bg.name("menu-main");
        menu_bg.path("menu-main.png");

        menu_opt_u.name("menu_opt_u");
        menu_opt_u.path("menu_opt_u.png");

        menu_opt_s.name("menu_opt_s");
        menu_opt_s.path("menu_opt_s.png");
    }
};
```

> Now, don't worry about SDL_Texture* if you havent used SDL before, the
> only thing you have to know about it is that you must use SDL
> functions to create and delete objects pointed to by them, not
> standard c++ alloc/malloc procedures like new and delete.  When
> ~TextResMgr() is called, it will go through each TextRes* in
> TextResMgr::TRvec and calls SDL_DestroyTexture() on that
> TextRes::Texture_.
>
> I made a little log macro utility that helps me follow objects around
> my program while executing by reporting information to the console.  I
> get this output from it:
>
> [log line number] [originating file] [file line number] [log message]

```
>      92 | STengMenu.h     L : 35  ~ST_eng_menu()
>      94 | TRL_MainMenu.h  L : 29  ~TRL_MainMenu()
>      95 | TextRes.h       L : 19  ~TextRes() : 006FFA68
>      97 | TextRes.h       L : 19  ~TextRes() : 006FFA5C
>      99 | TextRes.h       L : 19  ~TextRes() : 006FFA50
>     102 | TextResMgr.h    L : 23  ~TextResMgr()
>     104 | TextResMgr.cpp  L : 122 TextResMgr::del_all_t()
>     107 | SDLwrapper.h    L : 336 destroy_text(862bb0)
>     108 | TextResMgr.cpp  L : 112 TextRes: 006FFA50
>     110 | SDLwrapper.h    L : 336 destroy_text(86b6c0)
>     111 | TextResMgr.cpp  L : 112 TextRes: 006FFA5C
>     113 | SDLwrapper.h    L : 336 destroy_text(86b848)
>     114 | TextResMgr.cpp  L : 112 TextRes: 006FFA68
```

> ~TextRes() is called on lines 95, 97, and 99 and those lines also show
> the address to each of those objects.  ~TextResMgr() is called
> afterward at line 102 and line 104 calls a function to delete all the
> TextRes::Texture_'s for each TextRes in TextResMgr::TRvec. Line 107
> shows deleting a TextRes::Texture_ along with the texture's address
> and line 108 shows the address of the TextRes that texture was a
> member of.
>
> Clearly, the destructor was called on those exact same TextRes objects
> already, but here I am allowed to access its members still.  I have
> error checking throughout and can verify that those textures are
> deleted at that time.
>
> My thinking is that these TextRes objects came into scope with
> TRL_MainMenu and should go out of scope when TRL_MainMenu does,
> regardless if I have a reference to it somewhere else or not.   I
> understand that the SDL_Texture* member is on the heap and that
> accessing that should not be a problem if I had its address ahead of
> time, but the TextResMgr function that deletes TextRes::Texture_ gets
> a reference to that texture through a TextRes non-static member
> function, TextRes::text().
>
> Furthermore, ~TextRes() is never called again at any point.
>
> What is going on here?  I am blonde, am I just having a moment???
> This is all very easily fixed and I can control the flow of the
> program so that this situation doesn't even arise, but I am just stuck
> on how I can call TextRes::text() on a TextRes object after it has
> gone out of scope.

> using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 16.10.2

Comment: Undefined Behavior is _undefined_.  Accessing a deleted object is undefined behavior, and you are effectively asking "Why does my undefined behavior behave a certain way?"

Comment: Yeah, it was a blonde moment!  lol.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Clearly, the destructor was called on those exact same TextRes objects already, but here I am allowed to access its members still

You've assumed wrongly. You're not allowed to access its members after the destruction.

> What is going on here?

The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: Bblonde moment.  Thanks!